# Concatenating files in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to concatenate all .dat files in a specific directory (always different names) into one text file. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You can run dos under VBA:

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    oWSH.Run ("%comspec% /c copy c:\docs\conc\*.dat c:\docs\conc\onefile.txt")
```

You will need the /b switch if the files have a terminator and if the files do not end in a return, the lines will continue:

```
abc
defabc
def
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub a()
   Dim spath As String
   Dim intFileNum%, bytTemp As Byte
   spath = "c:\kk\"
   outFileNum = FreeFile
   Open spath + "Outfile.out" For Binary Access Write As outFileNum
   sdir = Dir$(spath & "*.dat", vbNormal)
   Do Until LenB(sdir) = 0
        inFileNum = FreeFile
        Open spath + sdir For Binary Access Read Lock Read As inFileNum
        Do While Not EOF(inFileNum)
          Get inFileNum, , bytTemp
          Put outFileNum, , bytTemp
        Loop
        Close inFileNum
        sdir = Dir$
   Loop
   Close outFileNum
End Sub
```

The only trick is that the [Dir$() has a weird iteration convention](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dir-function-HA001228824.aspx)

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I thought the above example might be faster than my version below
But on a 2 Mb audio file the above took 31 seconds cf 19 below
and Len = 1 or 100 or 1000 made no difference. Maybe the DOS wheeze is faster. My files can be hour long @ 128Kb baud rate.

```
 n=0
 k=0
 Do Until LenB(sdir) = 0
    inFileNum = FreeFile
    Open spath + sdir For Binary Access Read Lock Read As inFileNum Len = 1000
    Do While Not EOF(inFileNum)
      Get inFileNum, k, bytTemp
      k=k+1
      Put outFileNum, n, bytTemp
      n=n+1
    Loop
```